Group Array Object nested object by key and Iterate Through Them
I have an array object with nested objects inside. In each object of the array object is a nested object, i want to do the following:

Iterate through the testInfo property of the participantDetails property of the testObj arrayObject.

I want to create or get another object by using the JavaScript Object reduce function to group the Agency property of the participantDetails of participants property of the testObj array object.


I have written and edited my codes but couldn't get this right. Below are my code:
const testObj = [{
    id: 1,
    testName: 'Contingent/20sw',      
    testTest: 125,
    startDate: '19-10-2024',
    endDate: '21-11-2024',
    testCenter: 'Onne',
    participants:{     
      participantDetails: {       
          id: 1,     
          agency: 'Farehnsic Enterprise',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 25,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },    
      participantDetails: {
          id: 2,
          agency: 'Platinum Logistics',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },    
      participantDetails: {
          id: 3,
          agency: 'Chevron PLC',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },    
      participantDetails: {
          id: 4,
          agency: 'Glasgow Investment',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },    
      participantDetails: {
          id: 5,
          agency: 'Actual I.T Solutions',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },    
      participantDetails: {
          id: 6,
          agency: 'Oracle Inc.',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },
      
      participantDetails: {
          id: 7,
          agency: 'Oracle Inc.',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },
      participantDetails: {
          id: 8,
          agency: 'Pinquest Ventures',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },
      participantDetails: {
          id: 9,
          agency: 'Antiochist Enterprise',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },
      participantDetails: {
          id: 10,
          agency: 'Quantify Inc.',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },
      participantDetails: {
          id: 11,
          agency: 'Apple Inc.',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },
      participantDetails: {
          id: 12,
          agency: 'Datagin Inc.',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },
      participantDetails: {
          id: 13,
          agency: 'InfoMix Inc.',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  },
      participantDetails: {
          id: 14,
          agency: 'Sybase Inc.',
      agencyPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
      agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
      testTest: 35,
      testInfo:[{
        courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
        centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
        centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    },    
    {
        courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
        centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',            
    }],
  }
    },
    },
  }];


I have tried the following code but it wasn't giving me what I want. It was complaining of currentValue variable.
const groupedAgencies = testObj.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    (accumulator[currentValue.testObj.participants.participantDetails.agency] = accumulator[currentValue.testObj.participants.participantDetails.agency] || []).push(currentValue);
}, {});

console.log(`This uses the JS Reduce function to group the record base on a property from the JS object \n \n The following are Agencies on the TestObj Array Object: \n \n ${JSON.stringify(groupedAgencies)}`);

What I actually wanted to achieve are the following :

Iterate through the testInfo property of the participantDetails of the Participants property of the testObj arrayObject.

I want to create or get another object by using the JavaScript Object reduce function to group the Agency property of the participantDetails of participants property of the testObj array object.


I can easily do this from the MongoDB using Mongoose but I actually wanted to get the records off the database and use the Javascript to just do the operation at the frontend or the backend(controller) level with just Javascript code so as to release the database or the backend of long running job and allow the backend and database to serve other incoming request easily.

Note that testObj is an array object but SO wouldn't allow more than 30,000 character for the post. There are 5 objects in the testObj array object but they cannot fit in StackOverflow due to the rule of the SO post.

Bit hard to tell with the improper indentation, but presumably participants should be an array, not an object? Because with what you got there right now, it appears you are overwriting participantDetails multiple times.

Yes you are right, it's a fat finger error. I have it right in the real proj

Can you please [edit] your question to show the expected result. Also is there a reason why you want to use reduce() specifically and not something else that might be better?

Also does testObj really need to be that big for the purpose of this question? You can remove the unnecessary properties to make your question clearer / smaller. ie: create a [mre]

Make sure you have proper array structure "},"   is extra on second last line of testObj  array


  const testObj = [{
    id: 1,
    testName: 'Contingent/20sw',
    testTest: 125,
    startDate: '19-10-2024',
    endDate: '21-11-2024',
    testCenter: 'Onne',
    participants: {
      participantDetails: {
        id: 1,
        agency: 'Farehnsic Enterprise',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 25,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 2,
        agency: 'Platinum Logistics',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 3,
        agency: 'Chevron PLC',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 4,
        agency: 'Glasgow Investment',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 5,
        agency: 'Actual I.T Solutions',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 6,
        agency: 'Oracle Inc.',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },

      participantDetails: {
        id: 7,
        agency: 'Oracle Inc.',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 8,
        agency: 'Pinquest Ventures',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 9,
        agency: 'Antiochist Enterprise',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 10,
        agency: 'Quantify Inc.',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 11,
        agency: 'Apple Inc.',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 12,
        agency: 'Datagin Inc.',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 13,
        agency: 'InfoMix Inc.',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      },
      participantDetails: {
        id: 14,
        agency: 'Sybase Inc.',
        agencyPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyAltPhone: '07083590156',
        agencyEmail: 's.mail@gmail.com',
        testTest: 35,
        testInfo: [{
          courseNo: '690638HS738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '22, Muri Okunola Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '389474RY738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '33, Dangote Lane, Apapa-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '93788NB738/51YG',
          centerAddress: '11, Harley Grace Drive, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '490259FU003/51YG',
          centerAddress: '8, Martin Dell Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        },
        {
          courseNo: '846708GH462/51YG',
          centerAddress: '1, Adeola Orlean Road, VI-Lagos, Nigeria',
        }],
      }
    },
  }];  



const groupedAgencies = testObj.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    const participantDetails = currentValue.participants?.participantDetails;

    if (participantDetails) {
      const agency = participantDetails.agency;
      console.log('Agency:', agency);

      if (agency) {
        if (!accumulator[agency]) {
          accumulator[agency] = [];
        }
        accumulator[agency].push(currentValue);
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('No participantDetails found for:', currentValue);
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, {});

  console.log(`This uses the JS Reduce function to group the record based on a property from the JS object \n\nThe following are Agencies on the TestObj Array Object: \n\n${JSON.stringify(groupedAgencies, null, 2)}`);



